# Rails 6 - saving array attribute to model is removing last item from array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**Fixed** : if there's no comma after the last item in the array it will constantly remove the last item, so this won't work:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

But this will:

```
["one", "two", "three",]
```

---

I've got array attributes called "technologies" and "features" for my Project model. When I create a model the correct array length is passed in the params as expected, however when the params are set to a project the last item has been removed. Here's whats being passed in the params:

```
{"authenticity_token"=>"",
 "project"=>
  {"name"=>"test", "color"=>"", "url"=>"", "github"=>"", "technologies"=>"[\"one\", \"two\", \"three\"]", "description"=>"", "difficulties"=>"", "solution"=>"", "features"=>"one, two, three"},
 "commit"=>"Create Project"}
```

What the created project looks like:

```
=> #<Project id: nil, name: "test", color: "", url: "", github: "", technologies: ["one", " two"], description: "", difficulties: "", solution: "", features: ["ne", " two"], created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, slug: nil>
```

The strong params:

```
def strong_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :color, :url, :github, :technologies, :description, :difficulties, :solution, :features, photos: [])
end
```

The create method in the Projects controller:

```
 def create
    project = Project.new(strong_params)
    if project.save
      redirect_to project_path(project)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Here's the schema for the Project table:

```
    class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :color
      t.string :url
      t.string :github
      t.text :technologies, array: true, default: []
      t.text :description
      t.text :difficulties
      t.text :solution
      t.text :features, array: true, default: []

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas why it's doing this?

Edit:

Ran a test in the console and browser with the array: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]. Via the console it all works as expected, however on the browser it removes the last element:

```
[1] pry(main)> Project.create!(name: "test2", technologies: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], features: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Project Create (7.8ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("name", "technologies", "features", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "test2"], ["technologies", "{a,b,c,d,e}"], ["features", "{a,b,c,d,e}"], ["created_at", "2020-04-25 14:03:17.069772"], ["updated_at", "2020-04-25 14:03:17.069772"]]
   (1.7ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Project:0x00007ff48760e900
 id: 9,
 name: "test2",
 color: nil,
 url: nil,
 github: nil,
 technologies: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
 description: nil,
 difficulties: nil,
 solution: nil,
 features: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
 created_at: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 14:03:17 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 14:03:17 UTC +00:00>
[2] pry(main)> Project.last
  Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" ORDER BY "projects"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Project:0x00007ff48765e4c8
 id: 9,
 name: "test2",
 color: nil,
 url: nil,
 github: nil,
 technologies: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
 description: nil,
 difficulties: nil,
 solution: nil,
 features: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
 created_at: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 14:03:17 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 14:03:17 UTC +00:00>
[3] pry(main)> reload!
Reloading...
=> true
[4] pry(main)> Project.last
  Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" ORDER BY "projects"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Project:0x00007ff4880ffda0
 id: 10,
 name: "test3",
 color: "",
 url: "",
 github: "",
 technologies: ["a", " b", " c", " d"],
 description: "",
 difficulties: "",
 solution: "",
 features: ["a", " b", " c", " d"],
 created_at: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 14:04:38 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 14:04:38 UTC +00:00>
```

Comment: The split screen shot is a bit of a question. What's the scenario for the console commands versus the exception location in the browser? You could do strictly a console test which would be clearer: create a new record with some parameters, save it, and inspect it without involving the browser. Is it always the last element that is missing? If you had `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]` as your projects would you get `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`? Does the same thing happen with `features`?

Comment: Just tried on the console and it all works as expected, same array test via the browser and it's removed the last item from both the technologies and features array. Will add a photo of it to the original post.

Comment: That's good news. So there's an issue in the code in context. For completeness, you should show your `strong_params` method. You should also log values at each of the steps to confirm them. E.g., show what the value of `strong_params` is that you passed to `Project.new(...)` etc. You just have to dig into the details to find out what's different. By the way, don't use images. Put the text right in your question and format it there. Someone may down-vote you for the image approach. It's frowned upon on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the images, changed it all to code now. Strong_params is showing the correct data too.

Comment: The console test you did seems to indicate that the problem is not in your model. It's therefore likely in the controller. You should show the method used in the controller that is doing the database save.

Comment: Put the controller code in the OP. Used that same sort of method for previous apps with no issue.

Comment: Well, nothing jumps out as an issue for sure. There isn't a constraint anywhere on the length of the array item, is there? Your console test used "a", "b", "c", ... and your failing test was "one", "two", "three" with the last one being dropped off. I'd probably try a couple of other test case variations to see where it points. What happens with, `["three", "one", "two"]` or `["one", "two", "three", "four"]`? Does it always limit to two items, or is it doing something else? Also try `["one", "two", "three"]` in the console. Maybe understanding the behavior will be a good clue.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you did a browser test with `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]` and it dropped the `"e"`. So that rules out length constraint and says it always drops the last one.

Comment: The length of the array isn't an issue, it will always remove the last item regardless when created through the browser. I created a new rails app too to test it out and got the same issue. I worked around it by adding an empty string to the end of the array.

Comment: Sorted it, strangely enough if there's no comma after the last item in the array it will remove the last item. Put a comma at the end and it all works as expected.

Comment: Wow that actually seems like some kind of bug to me. I would never have guessed it. I know Ruby does optionally allow the trailing comma when entering a literal array. When you tried just two items, you had a comma at the end, like `["one", "two",]`? And your console tests didn't have a comma at the end. Your console test is different than your controller. In the console you used `.create!` whereas the controller uses `.new`. I wonder if they behave differently.

Comment: Good find, by the way! :)